# Controlling Spotify from ESP8266 (Arduino IDE)

Tags: arduino, spotify, esp8266

So  I want to control my Spotify from an ESP8266. I want to start with the basics so I can get a feel for the whole thing and be able to integrate it into other projects. Spotify gives these  curl commands to use, but ESP8266 isn't curl... Im not sure how to turn this: `curl -X "PUT" "https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/play" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer putsomerandomstuffherethisisanauthtoken"` into something the ESP can use... I already have the basic ESP libraries like `ESP8266WiFi.h` etc. If someone can point me in the right direction, that would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use the `HTTPClient` library.

Your code would look something like this:

```
#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>

#define SPOTIFY_AUTHORIZATION_TOKEN "Bearer putsomerandomstuffherethisisanauthtoken"

// easily get fingerprints with https://www.grc.com/fingerprints.htm
#define SPOTIFY_FINGERPRINT "AB:BC:7C:9B:7A:D8:5D:98:8B:B2:72:A4:4C:13:47:9A:00:2F:70:B5"

void spotify_play() {
  HTTPClient client;

  client.begin("https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/play", String(SPOTIFY_FINGERPRINT);

  client.addHeader("Accept", "application/json"");
  client.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
  client.addHeader("Content-Length", "0");
  client.addHeader("Authorization", SPOTIFY_AUTHORIZATION_TOKEN);

  int httpCode = client.sendRequest("PUT");
  if(httpCode == -1) {
    Serial.printf("http error: %s\n", http.errorToString(httpCode).c_str());
  } else {
    Serial.printf("HTTP status code %d\n", httpCode);
  }
}
```

The Spotify API docs should list what HTTP status codes they return on success or error. It should be something in the 200-range for success.

The fingerprint thing is to allow you to verify that you're really talking to the correct web site. When Spotify changes their SSL certificate you'll need to update the fingerprint. You don't need to do this with `curl` or on more capable systems because they're better able to very certificates. There's [been some work to make this easier on the ESP8266](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/libraries/ESP8266WiFi/examples/HTTPSRequestCACert/HTTPSRequestCACert.ino) but I'm not sure how reliable that is yet.

*[edited to add Content-length header]*

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've run the code, and I'm getting code 411. This isn't a Spotify code and from a quick google search, it means it's looking for a content length parameter... I can't find it in Spotify's original example command...

Comment: Try adding client.addHeader("Content-Length", "0"); with the other .addHeader() calls - order doesn't matter.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for all the help! It seems pretty simple now that I think about it.